# TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python

I am trying to parse the data that the user enters, I have read through a few other threads and tried fixing this issue but was not able to.

```
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Code:

```
from io import StringIO
import yaml
import sys

hostnames = input("Enter exact file path to hostnames: ")
with open(hostnames) as data:
    lines = data.readlines()


fh = StringIO(data)
data = {}  # start a new dictionary

for index, line in enumerate(fh):  # iterate by-line
    
    host = line.strip()  # do any needed validation here
    data[host] = {}  # start another dict to write to
    data[host]["nodename"] = line.strip()
    data[host]["domainname"] = f"{host}.example.com"
    data[host]['username'] = 'rundeck'
    data[host]["tags"] = 'rundeck'
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

I know this has something to do with opening the file and reading them as strings line by line, it confuses me because I looked at another similar project I have done to this and it works fine there.

Comment: `data` seems to want to be a file, then a string, then a dict.  Use a variable name for one purpose.

Comment: In `fh=StringIO(data)`, `data` is a _closed_ file.